# Creating a form from an object in python

Tags: python

Ok.. I am a noob to Python but work with PHP a lot.

Basically I am trying to figure out how to take an object -- for example:

```
{key:value,key:value}
```

or

```
{key:[value,value,value],key2:value2}
```

and turn them into forms:

```
<input name="key" value="value">
<input name="key" value="value">
```

and

```
<input name="key[]" value="value">
<input name="key[]" value="value">
<input name="key[]" value="value">
<input name="key2" value="value2">
```

Comment: Sure, we could give code that prints out strings like those you want. But this isn't what you should want to do. Why don't you use a templating engine? The problem would be reduced to a for loop and some HTML, and that's just one single, simple task... I've seen code that builds HTML manually. I know why I advertise templating engines.

Comment: somthing missing in your question! what forms you want to turn to?

Comment: your first example is impossible in Python: you can't have two dict entries with the same key (it's impossible in PHP as well I believe)

Comment: is easy in python you need template like mako & jinjia,etc....

Comment: jcomeau_ictx I know that... the above was just an example and was too lazy to write out key1, key2, etc. figured who ever saw this and had an answer would be smart enough ti figure that out :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a template with the structure of the html.
Then you can replace #key# and #value# for the real values.

```
template = '<input name="#key#" value="#value#">'
html = template
data = {key:value,key:value}
for key in data.keys():
    html = html.replace("#key#", key).replace("#value#", data[value]) + "\n"
    html = html + template
#there's an extra template line here that you'll have to get rid of.
html = "\n".join(html.split("\n")[0:-1])
```

Something similar for your second example.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this.  1: it doesn't work, you don't actually iterate over the dict values anywhere, and don't compose or yield any data.  2: you are using `str.replace` instead of `str.format` or `str % (data,)` to no obvious benefit.

Comment: That's right, you should use for key in {dictionary}.keys(), I'll correct. Thanks.

Comment: the important part is not the `data.keys()` but the `data[key]` to actually get the value.  Even with your edits it's still off.  In fact, `iter(data)` is preferrable to `iter(data.keys())` since it avoids creating a list of all of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `forms` for web sites , I recommend `wtf`, here is the link for Integrating with `Flask`.http://packages.python.org/Flask-WTF/

WTF site => http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of options for dealing with form creation and validation in Python.  If you are using Django, [it has form building and validation built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).  If you are building a stand-alone tool, you have [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/), [z3c.form](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.form), [deform](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/dev/) ... and that's just the short list.

A couple of things to note, if you are coming from a PHP background:

1. Python is not a templating language - it is a general purpose language. PHP was developed first and foremost to make it easy to create dynamic web pages - so it is extremely easy to embed PHP in HTML and call it a day.  Python does not make that nearly as easy to slap something together all in one file (although you can do some pretty impressive things using only multi-line strings, concatenation and `.format`).  You'll want to check out a templating library - take a look at Jinja2, Mako, Breve, or Chameleon and pick the one that seems most intuitive to you.
2. You don't need to use the `I_am_an_array[]` construct in your HTML if you are planning on returning multiple values for a single name.  Any library you use ([including the built-in one](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#higher-level-interface)) supports receiving multiple values for a single name and will handle things appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, whatever, teh codes:

```
import cgi
FIELD = '<input name="%s%s" value="%s">\n'
def formulate(ob):
    def _formulate():
        for k, v in ob.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                for i in v:
                    yield FIELD % (k, '[]', cgi.escape(i, True))
            else:
                yield FIELD % (k, '', cgi.escape(v, True))
    return ''.join(_formulate())
```