# Python -- Create a Webform

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, webforms, google-forms

I'm working on a project to try and create a more streamlined process to enter data into our database.

Currently, we're just using raw_input("Question: "), but this seems very outdated and is prone to mistakes. Given that there are over 100 questions we need to answer, this can take quite some time, loading only one question at a time.

I was interested in creating a web-based form to do this instead, as individuals wouldn't need to install python and various libraries on their own computers, but connect to an IP address on our network instead.

However, they're going to be using this to input medical data into our database, so I need some sort of secure-login feature, and only after being "validated", is a technician redirected to our medical form. I saw that using FlaskWTF might be able to solve this issue, but their documentation is a little confusing to me.

I'm wondering exactly how to do this. I've been looking at FlaskWTF (recommended on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170064/creating-a-form-from-an-object-in-python)), but I don't need the ability to upload documents, only get data from a text box, or to see if someone has selected multiple boxes (i.e., if the person indicates they have both cancer AND diabetes).

Likewise, I'm wondering if I can create a google form, download it, and host it on an internal server. However, I'm curious on how I can retrieve the data with Python. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964429/google-forms-response-with-python), but its only for a one question form, and I have at least 100 questions on this form.

If you think creating a webform is too difficult for someone who has no major python web experience, nor experience with HTML/PHP (I've mostly worked with databases using elasticsearch and some, albeit very basic, python-based AI/Chatterbots), would you recommend creating a form using TKinker instead? If so, how to I save form inputs as variables, and make it look a little prettier?

My apologies that I don't have code here, but rather a series of questions. As I continue to work on this project, I will probably post snippits of code to this site.

Best!